# PHP: Como pegar exceção lançada pelo modelo no controller

Tags: php, exceção

Eu criei uma classe para conectar à LDAP, num dos métodos eu fiz o seguinte:

```
// Classe Ldap()
public function ldapConnection() {

    $this->_ldapCon = ldap_connect($this->_ldapServer);

    if ($this->_ldapCon) {

        ldap_set_option($this->_ldapCon, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

        ldap_set_option($this->_ldapCon, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

        return $this->_ldapCon;

    } else {

        throw new Exception('Não foi possível conectar ao servidor LDAP');

    }

}
```

Se eu fizer

```
$conexao = new Ldap();

try {

    $conexao->ldapConnection();

} catch (Exception $ex) {

    // Abaixo, não pega a exceção que eu lancei no método. A exceção lançada no método aparece como "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message: Não foi possível conectar ao servidor LDAP"
    echo json_encode(array('message' => $ex->getMessage()));

}
```

**Como é que eu pego a exceção exata lançada pelo método da classe LDAP e não apenas uma exceção genérica?**

Comment: Não se tiver nada padrão deve criar sua classe personalizada de exception e depois capturar no catch.

Comment: Mas os blocos `try/catch` só vão avaliar a exceção lançada pelo método dentro deles? Ou outra exceção pode ser lançada, além da que eu mesmo definir?

Comment: O bloco `try/catch` dado deveria estar capturando a exceção. A classe `Ldap` faz parte de algum `namespace`?

Comment: Sim. Faz parte do `namespace Models`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, se a class Ldap está presente dentro de algum namespace, para você disparar e/ou capturar a Exception, você precisa coloca-la no namespace global, isto é, disparar e capturar usando `\Exception`.

Para pegar uma Exception específica pela classe LDAP, primeiramente você tem que criar sua própria classe de Exception, por exemplo:

```
class LdapException extends \Exception{}
```

Então no seu método `Ldap::ldapConnection()` você coloca:

```
// Classe Ldap()
public function ldapConnection() {

    $this->_ldapCon = ldap_connect($this->_ldapServer);

    if ($this->_ldapCon) {
        ldap_set_option($this->_ldapCon, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

        ldap_set_option($this->_ldapCon, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

        return $this->_ldapCon;
    } else {
        throw new LdapException('Não foi possível conectar ao servidor LDAP');
    }
}
```

E para capturar:

```
$conexao = new Ldap();

try {
    $conexao->ldapConnection();
} catch (LdapException $ex) {
    echo json_encode(array('message' => $ex->getMessage()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usei a ideia do @LucasMendes e cheguei ao seguinte resultado:

Criei a classe de exceções estendendo a classe `\Exception`, porém tive que fazer uma modificação: adicionar os construtores.

```
namespace Models;

class AppExceptions extends \Exception
{
    public function __construct($message, $code = 0, \Exception $previous = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }
}
```

Depois na *classe Ldap()*:

```
protected function conexaoLdap()
{
    $this->_conexao = ldap_connect($this->servidor_ldap);
    if ($this->_conexao) {
        ldap_set_option($this->_conexao, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        ldap_set_option($this->_conexao, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
        return $this->_conexao;
    } else {
        throw new AppExceptions('Não foi possível se conectar ao servidor LDAP');
    }
}
```

Pegando a exceção:

```
try {
    // Code goes here
} catch (AppExceptions $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Por quê teve que adicionar o construtor sendo que no mesmo você fez a chamada direta ao construtor da classe pai? Se não possuir lógica a mais, não precisa sobrescrever o método.